# Sendgrid email route to Gmail

Tags: sendgrid, mailgun

I am aware of Sendgrid's [parse webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Parse_Webhook/inbound_email.html) functionality. What I want, however, is a (non-programmatic) way to route incoming emails to me@domain.com to my Gmail address, using a specific match or a catch-all.

Some context: This used to be trivial on Mailgun using inbound routes until they required a paid plan to have that functionality. I still receive emails sent to the routes I created before Mailgun removed that functionality.

Comment: Any help or link will be appreciated!